# Taking into account line-of-sight & blast rules, how would a blast work with a wall between you and an enemy?

Tags: dnd-4e, line-of-sight, line-of-effect

If you take into effect the blast rules and the line-of-sight rules, how should we play the blast? Would it wrap the nine squares in front of him, including the wall? Would it go the nine diagonal that would then hit the Goblin?

[image: blast & line of sight]

Thanks for any help on the matter!

Comment: Is this a blast 3 power? Is the attacker in the location shown in the second pic?

Comment: @wax eagle: Yes. Using a blast 3 and the pictures we see.

Comment: My 4e books are packed up at the moment, but I believe that there is a rule that states that line of effect is required to each square in the blast. Hopefully someone can dig up an actual citation.

Comment: @Ace - would that be origin square of blast or creature's current square?

Comment: @WaxEagle For a blast, I believe it requires LoE from the caster to each target (targets without LoE are immune). For a burst, I believe it is from the origin square. But without my books I must leave the search for the citation to others.

Comment: Since you are including an image, it would be helpful if you overlaid your proposed blast to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: I would DM Fiat a resounding "no." Simply based on the "you can't cast a spell *in* a wall!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the diagram shown, a blast 3 power would not effect either of the targets there is nowhere to start a blast that would reach them. However, were the character to move up one square they would be able to use the top right corner as the start of the blast and actually effect both targets with no penalty.

There are two reason for this.

1. The blast would not reach the targets. You have line of effect to the Bugbear, but the blast will not reach him.
2. If the blast were larger it would reach the Bugbear but not the goblin as there is blocking terrain in the way. I believe the Bugbear would have cover depending on the origin square as one of the line would be blocked.

Comment: +1: Trace lines from the origin square to determine cover, superior cover and line of effect as per Dungeon Master's Guide, page 43.